# Seperate AngularJS controller files with local HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to run a local webpage with AngularJS with dynamically driven controllers.  I'd like a URL variable to drive which particular javascript file is loaded with data to drive my page.

**HTML File**

```
<html>
    <head >
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        </script>

        <script>
            var url = new URL(window.location.href);
            var t_var= url.searchParams.get("t_var");
            var x = document.createElement('script');
            x.src = t_var +'.js';
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='Ctrl1'>
        {{sub1Variable}}
    </body>
</html>
```

**AngularJS controller**

```
app.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope) {
    $scope.sub1Variable = 'sub1'
});
```

I have been able to get this to work if I include the below tag in the HTML file.

```
<script src="sub1.js"></script>
```

I keep receiving an error that a controller with this name is not referenced.

Answer (score 0):

In principle what you are doing here should be fine. See below.

```js
app.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope) {
    $scope.sub1Variable = 'sub1'
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head >
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='Ctrl1'>
        {{sub1Variable}}
    </body>
</html>
```

If you run that you should see 'sub1' in the output.

So, if you are receiving the error saying that your controller isn't registered then almost certainly the problem is you aren't loading the JavaScript file that contains your controller registration. Make sure the script that contains the `app.controller...` line is included through a `<script>` element at some point after loading angular and registering the module.

(Remember the SO Snippet and CodePen etc will implicitly include the JavaScript for convenience, in real code we need to do it ourselves).

In fact, if this is just a quick local app maybe you can just include it in the same script element as the module registration, like so:

```html
<html>
    <head >
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
            app.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope) {
                 $scope.sub1Variable = 'sub1'
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='Ctrl1'>
        {{sub1Variable}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm wanting to dynamically drive the javascript file that the controller resides in.  i'm not sure if this is a function of it being a local app, or angular itself.